# Why is Django letting me instantiate a model without a required field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model in Django (using v4.0):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(OtherModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.FloatField(default=0)

    # Some methods ...
```

My question is why I don'get any errors when I execute anywhere the following code:

```
new_model = MyModel.objects.create(owner=get_valid_owner(), value=500)
```

Shouldn't `name` be required since I did not set `blank=True` to it?

If I got it wrong, how can I make that field required?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `new_model.save()` ...

Comment: @JonClements I believe `create` should call save automatically, but I even tried to call it manually and still it is allowing me to do that

Comment: There's no signals and nothing in your methods that automatically populates name somehow? (eg: you've not overriden `save` to do something for instance?)

Comment: @JonClements Not at all, just few methods, but no signals or any stuff that gets automatically called in any way

Comment: And if I check my object in the db or from the admin page, it actually has the `name` field empty

Comment: Weird - is it an empty string or an actual null?

Comment: @JonClements Just empty. If instead I remove the default value from the `value` field, I actually get an IntegrityError if I try to initialize it without a `value`

Comment: Your migrations are all up to date?

Comment: @JonClements Yes, I'm still in early stages, so I just created an empty DB, deleted all existing migrations, made new ones and applied them to a clean DB, but still same results

Comment: `blank=True` will only be validated when running `full_clean` or `clean_fields` method. It performs validation on the code level, not the database level.  And since `save` doesn't call the `full_clean` or `clean_fields` method, empty string is saved in the database. What you can do is call one of those methods manually before calling `.save`.

Comment: If you want to create a constraint that `name` cannot be an empty string in the database, you may use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint).